# Error loading NEXRAD file into bioRad - file not found

Tags: r, docker, rstudio

I am trying to read a NEXRAD polar volume using bioRad in R Studio, but I get an error saying the file does not exist when it does in fact exist in the proper directory.  Any thoughts on how to solve this?

input code:
`read_pvolfile("/directory/FOP120200101_000209_V06")`

result:

````
Error: input file 'FOP120200101_000209_V06' does not exist.
Error in nexrad_to_odim_tempfile(file, verbose = verbose, mount = mount) : 
  Failed to run nexrad_to_odim (rsl2odim) in Docker container.```
````

Comment: What does `file.exists("/directory/FOP120200101_000209_V06")` return?

Comment: It returns "true".  I think this is an error having to do with Docker

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  I was using version 0.40 of bioRad and version 0.50 of the vol2bird docker container.  Upgrading to the latest development version of bioRad solved this issue.

This is done by installing using `devtools::install_github("adokter/bioRad")`